# ¿Cómo mostrar la fecha en formato DD-MM-AAAA?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código que utilizo para mostrar un `placeholder` en un campo `date`, cuando selecciono la fecha me muestra el formato `AAAA-MM-DD` y necesito que lo muestre en el formato: `DD-MM-AAA`

```
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-lg-3"  type="text" name="start" placeholder="Desde" onclick="ocultarError();" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')">
```

Answer (score 0):

En esta página han encontrado una solución para el problema que comentas:
https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/html5/hay-alguna-forma-de-cambiar-el-tipo-de-entrada-fecha/940044198/

Parece ser que utilizando solo HTML no es posible, pero si que es posible modificando el texto que se muestra en el input, usando javascript (jquery en este caso) y css: https://jsfiddle.net/kzqu8rop/

**Código js**

```
$("input").on("change", function() {
    this.setAttribute(
        "data-date",
        moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
        .format( this.getAttribute("data-date-format") )
    )
}).trigger("change")
```

**Código CSS**

```
input {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px; height: 20px;
    color: white;
}

input:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px; left: 3px;
    content: attr(data-date);
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}

input::-webkit-datetime-edit, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 toma el formato de fecha de la configuracion del navegador del usuario [HTML5 DATE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el siguiente código para formatear la fecha

```
Date.prototype.DDMMYYYY = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var MM = pad(this.getMonth() + 1, 2);
    var dd = pad(this.getDate(), 2);

    return dd +"-"+ MM +"-"+ yyyy;
};

function pad(number, length) {

    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) {
        str = '0' + str;
    }

    return str;

}

//Ejemplo
const time = new Date();
const format = time.DDMMYYYY();
console.log(format);
```